# Unable to find icons using automation script execution using Katalon Studio

Tags: ios, automated-tests, ios-simulator, katalon-studio

While writing mobile automation script for iOS in Katalon Studio, there is a "View Password" icon on my page which is working fine as expected when the script is recorded. But the same does not work when test case is executed. It does not get tapped as written in the script.

Also there are many other icons that act as tappable buttons in App . I tried capturing those objects too. But , all of those did not get tapped when I executed test cases. I am unable to understand why katalon is unable to find the element that was captured easily during recording.

There is one thing I noticed about all these objects. Such objects are not having any name and label.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to add id for each button(icon) as tag in iOS.

```
let buttonOne() : UIButton { 
   let button = UIButton(type: .system)
   button.backgroundColor = .red
   **button.tag = 2**
   return button
}()
```

then if you open Your page You can look for html tag.

Comment: Hi @siranen - I believe that I have a similar problem. Would you mind taking a look at this question for me please?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721320/in-katalon-studio-how-to-tap-an-ios-app-s-element-when-it-doesn-t-have-either-la
Your prompt response will be highly appreciated!