# In Katalon Studio how to tap an iOS app’s element when it doesn’t have either label or name object properties

Tags: ios, automated-tests, katalon-studio

KS 6.3.2 is able to tap on an element that contains label or name object properties. However, the application that I have under test has an element which is a button and does not contain either label or name or any text. Furthermore, the xpath of that element is dynamic.

**The following are the snapshots of the Object’s properties of the same element of an application captured from 2 different devices:**

[image]

[image]

**The following is the Selected Locator’s value:**

My Page 1:

```
//XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[1]/XCUIElementTypeTabBar[1]/XCUIElementTypeButton[6][count(. | //[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’ and @height = ‘96.0’ and @visible = ‘true’ and @width = ‘160.0’ and @x = ‘664.0’ and @y = ‘1628.0’]) = count(//[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’ and @height = ‘96.0’ and @visible = ‘true’ and @width = ‘160.0’ and @x = ‘664.0’ and @y = ‘1628.0’])]
```

My Page 2:

```
//XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1]/XCUIElementTypeOther[2]/XCUIElementTypeTabBar[1]/XCUIElementTypeButton[6][count(. | //[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’ and @height = ‘96.0’ and @visible = ‘true’ and @width = ‘142.0’ and @x = ‘604.0’ and @y = ‘1238.0’]) = count(//[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’ and @height = ‘96.0’ and @visible = ‘true’ and @width = ‘142.0’ and @x = ‘604.0’ and @y = ‘1238.0’])]
```

As you can see above that the following object properties values are not static:
width
x
y
xpath

However, the xpath’s starts-with and ends-with values are more or less constant.
xpath constant starts-with value is: //XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOr9.png)
xpath constant ends-with value is: /XCUIElementTypeTabBar[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FOr9.png)/XCUIElementTypeButton[6]

**I have tried with xpath starts-with and ends-with values but it didn’t work. So any suggestion will be highly appreciated. They are as follows:**

**xpath ends-with selected locators value:**

```
/XCUIElementTypeTabBar[1]/XCUIElementTypeButton[6][count(. | //[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’]) = count(//[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’])]
```

**xpath starts-with selected locators value:**

```
//XCUIElementTypeApplication/XCUIElementTypeWindow[1][count(. | //[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’]) = count(//[@type = ‘XCUIElementTypeButton’ and @enabled = ‘true’])]
```

DOM tree snippet:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging and research, I found the following methods to solve my problem:

> 1) With the help of appium-desktop, I was able to get the (x,y)
>   co-ordinates of the element. Then in KS, I used the method called
>   tapAtPosition(x,y) to tap at the icon. However, this is not the final
>   way I ended up using.
>
> 2) I ended up creating a relative xpath for the element using KS spy
>   mobile. This was my final relative xpath for the element:
>   //*/XCUIElementTypeButton[6]

Answer (score 0):

There would be an easy way to avoid this if you can modify the source:

-Add a unique property to the element (<... data-tagging="ThisIsMyUniqueTag">...

-In the objects definition in Katalon, add an attribute called data-tagging and set the value to your unique tag

-Use only that to locate the object (if there are multiple occurances you might wanna use different tags, or select a specific one [1])

Pros: Efficient, increases maintainability, doesn't break when other things are changed
Con: You need to be able to do that

Otherwise try to inspect the and manually write a selector. Could you provide some sample of the DOM-tree?

Comment: Hi @user11966992 - Unfortunately, stack overflow doesn't allow users to add images in a comment. Hence please see my answer post above and there I added a snippet of the DOM-tree you requested.

Comment: can you also show some of the regarding HTML code, like are there different attributes that may be usable for selection?

Comment: Hi @user11966992 - I've used KS 6.3.2 to capture the object's properties values and they are all provided in the above question I've posted. I'm a bit confused about what HTML code are you looking forward to? I'd appreciate if you can guide me on how to capture HTML code of an iOS application's element.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking of a Web Application, my fault, Can you add properties to the objects? Otherwise my only Idea would be to make relative paths based on the "phrase tabbar" element.

Comment: All the captured object property values have been added in the form of an image in the question above that I posted. 
The following is an example:
Name, Condition, Value
type, equals, XCUIElementTypeButton
enabled, equals, true

Comment: Yes, all the captured ones, but my idea was to artificially add some in the code to be captured just for this object

Comment: Hi @user11966992 - Unfortunately, I'm unable to apprehend your last comment. The part that I couldn't understand:
"..artificially add some in the code.." - What do you exactly want to add in the code? Can you kindly give an example? I believe that might help!